# Eclipse Watch Expression

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I would love a feature to put a breakpoint and stop there when a certain expression is true. Can this be accomplished with Expressions in Eclipse? Can someone give me an example (preferrable java)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Add a breakpoint
2. right-click the breakpoint and choose "Breakpoint properties"
3. Check "Enable condition"

Comment: I'm evaluating a string so I put 'object.getName().equals("test")' in Enable condition. But I get a Exception processing async thread queue
  Exception processing async thread queue
  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

why is that?

Comment: seems to be a bug (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716271/eclipse-debugging-problem)

Could be true since I'm using an older eclipse version

Answer (score 3):

Yes check [this Example from the Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/breakpoints/ref-condition_option.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by clicking to the left of a line # in the code, you can set a breakpoint that the debugger will then stop at when you run the debugger in the Debug perspective.  You can then look at the "Breakpoints" tab in that perspective and right click your breakpoint and choose "Properties", and there you can set a condition for the breakpoint to fire.